# tslint be strict on optional member variables

Tags: typescript, tslint

i like the tslint to check that my objects are well formed. this means 
1) are mandatory elements are present
2) only optional members can be present

nr 1) is working fine. with 2) i do not know how to enable it in the compiler

here the example

```
export interface MyDto {
    lastName: string;
    firstName?: string;
}
```

so the following data are correct and give no typescript warings

```
myData: MyDto ={
    "lastName":"Joe"
}
```

or

```
myData: MyDto ={
    "lastName":"Joe",
    "firstName":"Max"
}
```

But this should fail, as the dateOfBirth is not defined in the scheme

```
myData: MyDto ={
    "lastName":"Joe",
    "firstName":"Max",
    "dateOfBirth":"2015-12-24"
}
```

Or is there even a typescript compiler option i can use? I did not see this one.

Answer (score 3):

In TypeScript 1.6+, the following code:

```
export interface MyDto {
    lastName: string;
    firstName?: string;
}

let myData: MyDto ={
    "lastName":"Joe"
}

let myData2: MyDto ={
    "lastName":"Joe",
    "firstName":"Max",
    "dateOfBirth":"2015-12-24"  // Error
}
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=export%20interface%20MyDto%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3F%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20myData%3A%20MyDto%20%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%22Joe%22%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20myData2%3A%20MyDto%20%3D%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22lastName%22%3A%22Joe%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%22Max%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22dateOfBirth%22%3A%222015-12-24%22%0A%7D)]

throws the following error:

```
main.ts(13,5): error TS2322: Type '{ "lastName": string; "firstName": string; "dateOfBirth": string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyDto'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"dateOfBirth"' does not exist in type 'MyDto'.
```

So you don't need a tslint rule for this.